# Delphi appearance change will not let me drag a borderless window

Tags: delphi

I'm having an issue when changing the appearance of my window.  For some reason, I can't drag my borderless window. I can drag the window, but I can't grab the corners to make the size of the window bigger. It's for a screenshot app.

[image: capture window area]

```
 procedure TFrmCapture.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
const
  SC_DRAGMOVE = $F012;
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then
  begin
    ReleaseCapture;
    Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_DRAGMOVE, 0);
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmCapture.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_DOWN then
    self.Top := self.Top + 1;
  if Key = VK_UP then
    self.Top := self.Top - 1;
  if key = VK_LEFT then
    self.Left := self.Left - 1;
  if key = VK_RIGHT then
    self.Left := self.Left + 1;

end;

procedure TfrmCapture.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if MouseIsDown then
  begin
    ReleaseCapture;
    Self.Perform(WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0);
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmCapture.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  MouseIsDown := False;
end;

procedure TfrmCapture.mnuCaptureClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Set button press
  ButtonPress := 1;
  //Get window rect.
  GetWindowRect(Handle, WindowInfo.wRect);
  //Set left and top form pos.
  WindowInfo.X := Left;
  WindowInfo.Y := Top;
  //Close form.
  Close;
end;

procedure TfrmCapture.mnuCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ButtonPress := 0;
  Close;
end;
```

Comment: Borderless windows are not supposed to be resized. But there was a similar trick for window resize (bottom right), `SC_DRAGSIZE = $F008`. Your code is a bit weird (e.g. you never set that `MouseIsDown` flag).

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much :D

Comment: Maybe in those resize box mouse down events you can send `SC_SIZE + WMSZ_<edge>` according to which edge that box controls. That `SC_DRAGSIZE` constant is just `SC_SIZE + WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT`. The edge constants you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms632647(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I'm total noob at Delphi, I just started a week ago. I have been developing with VB.NET and C# for awhile.

Comment: I mean, writing `OnMouseDown` event handlers for those resize boxes. For instance for the top left one you could write `ReleaseCapture; Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_SIZE or WMSZ_TOPLEFT, 0);`

Comment: FYI, your image link is broken, did the file get deleted?

Comment: Ya I built a desktop cleaner in Delphi that moved all my files around, learning is fun and troublesome at times lol.